# Laravel query multiple tables using eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

hi sorry bit of a newbie here but I am have three tables users, profiles, friends. they all have the user_id fields within them and I want fetch all of the fields in one statement using Eloquent and not `DB::statement` and doing the table joins.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

use the `User` class and the `with` method that laravel has to query model relationships

```
$user = User::with(['profile', 'friend'])->get();
```

Ensure your models has the correct relationships as follows:

```
app/models/User.php

public function friend () {
    return $this->hasMany('Friend');
}

public function profile () {
    return $this->hasOne('Profile');
}

app/models/Profile.php

  public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');

    }

app/models/Friend.php

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use some thing like this:
You should define relations in your models with hasOne, hasMany.

```
class Review extends Eloquent {
    public function relatedGallery()
    {
        $this->hasOne('Gallery', 'foreign_id', 'local_id');
    }
}

class Gallery extends Eloquent {
    public function relatedReviews()
    {
        $this->hasMany('Review', 'foreign_id', 'local_id');
    }
}

$gallery = Gallery::with('relatedReviews')->find($id);
Will bring the object Gallery with

$gallery->id
gallery->name
...

$gallery->relatedReviews // array containing the related Review Objects
```