# Query a model using a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called `unit` that has this relationship

```js
/**
 * Get the users associated with the unit
 */
public function users()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User\UserData');
}
```

In the `UserData` model there is a column called `user_id` which I am trying to put in my condition in my query. I am trying to do a query like this

```js
Unit::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first()
```

but there is no `user_id` column in the `Unit` table, only though the `users` relationship

Comment: `UserData` is pivot table ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel query multiple tables using eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036781/laravel-query-multiple-tables-using-eloquent)

Comment: of course, you have to specify foreign id and local id in the relation to use the advantage of the relation, please see this link: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing this

```php
Unit::whereHas('users', function($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', Auth::id());
})->first();
```